# Understanding Cohn's Radon-Nikodym proof from his book on measure theory

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

The part of the proof which I don't get is $$\nu(A)=\int_{A} g\ \mathsf d\mu$$ where $g$ is Radon-Nikodym derivative. He has a set of functions for which $$\int_{A} f\ \mathsf dx \le \nu(A) ,$$ he has just shown the $g$ is in this set and therefore he can define a positive measure $$\nu_0=\nu(A)-\int_{A} g\ \mathsf d\mu$$ His goal is to get $\nu_0=0$. So he assumes for a contradiction that there is an $\epsilon$ such that $\nu_0(X) >\epsilon \mu(X)$ ($\mu$ is positive). The he considers the Hahn decomposition of the signed measure $\nu_0-\epsilon \mu$ and remarks that $$\nu_0(A \cap P) \ge \epsilon \mu(A \cap P )$$ which he uses to deduce $$\nu(A) \ge\int_{A} (g +\epsilon\chi_{P})\ \mathsf d\mu.$$  Next he remarks that $\mu(P) > 0 $ and deduces $$\nu_0(X)-\epsilon \mu(X)=(\nu_0-\epsilon \mu)(N) \le 0.$$ I cant see how he gets these last couple of relations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are misreading him. Cohn doesn't remark $\mu(P)>0$ and then deduce 
$\nu_0(X)-\epsilon \mu(X)=(\nu_0-\epsilon \mu)(N) \le 0.$

Rather, *he proves* $\mu(P)>0$ by showing that if, to the contrary, $\mu(P)=0$
were true, then he could deduce $\nu_0(X)-\epsilon \mu(X)=(\nu_0-\epsilon \mu)(N) \le 0,$ which he has already shown to be impossible.